# How to get the correct SELECT statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ms-access-2007

I am very new to SQL, MS Access & PostgreSQL. I was given this querying task on a very short notice. I read about basic SQL syntaxes first and then wrote this just with logic. Somehow I get this `SELECT` error:

[[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqjFy.png]]

The table and column names are correct. Here is a short description of what my aim is
[image]

```
SELECT 
  change_incoming_area AS Bodenfläche, 
  CASE 
    WHEN change_type_id = 2 
    AND (NOT cng.city_old_id=cng.city_new_id 
    AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cng.date_change) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM tb_city_annual_population.population_year)) THEN 
      ROUND((cng.change_incoming_area/SELECT pop.city_area FROM tb_city_annual_population pop WHERE pop.city_id=cng.city_old_id)*100,2)
    WHEN change_type_id = 2
    AND (cng.city_old_id=cng.city_new_id 
    AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cng.date_change) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM tb_city_annual_population.population_year) 
    AND cng.change_incoming_area<SELECT pop.city_area FROM tb_city_annual_population pop WHERE pop.city_id=cng.city_old_id) THEN
      ROUND(((SELECT pop.city_area FROM tb_city_annual_population pop WHERE pop.city_id=cng.city_old_id AS origarea-cng.change_incoming_area)/origarea)*100,2)
    WHEN change_type_id = 2 
    AND (cng.city_old_id=cng.city_new_id 
    AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cng.date_change) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM tb_city_annual_population.population_year) 
    AND ((cng.change_incoming_area+SELECT pop.city_area FROM tb_city_annual_population pop WHERE pop.city_id=cng.city_old_id AS origarea3)/origarea3)*100>100) THEN
      ROUND(((cng.change_incoming_area+SELECT pop.city_area FROM tb_city_annual_population pop WHERE pop.city_id=cng.city_old_id AS origarea2)/origarea2)*100,2)
    ELSE 100 
  END 
FROM tb_change cng;
```

Comment: Syntax errors.  The SELECT's inside another SELECT (i.e. a sub-query) must be enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to do. Perhaps you could do JOIN's instead of all those sub-queries?

Comment: Simplify until it works. Then you know where the problem was, and can focus on that.

Comment: And you want to run the exact same query in PostqreSQL and MS Access?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner:  From the picture above, I can see that the query "Afrage3" is a pass through query. This means that is has to be formulated in the SQL dialect of the back-end; in this case PostgreSQL.

Comment: Is SQL for PostgreSQL very different than regular SQL? I thought it will be the same so didn't even consider this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jarlh commented immediately: a subquery must be in parentheses.

This line

```
  ROUND( ( cng.change_incoming_area / select ... ) * 100, 2)
```

must be

```
  ROUND( ( cng.change_incoming_area / (select ...) ) * 100, 2)
```

or simply

```
  ROUND( cng.change_incoming_area / (select ...) * 100, 2)
```

As to the subquery itself: it must result in one value only of course. With a table name `tb_city_annual_population` I'd expect it to have a record per city and year. But in your where clause, you only limit by city:

```
  SELECT pop.city_area 
  FROM tb_city_annual_population pop 
  WHERE pop.city_id = cng.city_old_id
```

Doesn't that give you several records (one for each year)? Maybe you want it to be something like this instead:

```
  SELECT pop.city_area 
  FROM tb_city_annual_population pop 
  WHERE pop.city_id = cng.city_old_id
  AND pop.year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cng.date_change)
```

There are more errors:

```
ROUND(((cng.change_incoming_area+SELECT pop.city_area FROM tb_city_annual_population pop 
        WHERE pop.city_id=cng.city_old_id AS origarea2)/origarea2)*100,2)
```

What is the `AS origarea2` for? You cannot use AS in the middle of an expression. It should be

```
ROUND((cng.change_incoming_area + (SELECT pop.city_area FROM tb_city_annual_population pop 
       WHERE pop.city_id = cng.city_old_id)) / origarea2 * 100, 2)
```

Same for `AS origarea3` and `AS origarea`.

Then in

```
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cng.date_change) = 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM tb_city_annual_population.population_year)) THEN
```

you refer to `tb_city_annual_population.population_year`, but you don't select from `tb_city_annual_population`, you select from `tb_change`.

Then you extract the year from `population_year`. So `population_year` is a date? The name suggests it's an integer representing a year.

Comment: I put the parenthesis around both the sub-query 'SELECT' statements but still get the same error.

Comment: yes you are correct I added the year part too to the sub-queries now. But still I get errors.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show more errors. There may be even more. I'd suggest you build your query from small to big, so you find errors easier. E.g. start with one WHEN clause only. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks so much for your input I'll systematically correct errors starting from small.